# Combinação de valores distintos

Tags: r, combinações

Considerando um dataframe com 2 colunas pretende-se, para cada valor distinto da coluna origem:

1. selecionar os valores correspondentes presentes na coluna destino
2. formar combinações 2 a 2 de elementos distintos com base nos valores do ponto 1
3. registar resultado num novo dataframe.

Exemplo de aplicação:

```
df <- data.frame(
    origem = c("A","A", "A", "E", "E", "D", "D", "D", "D"), 
    destino=c("B","A","C","C", "B", "A","A", "A","B"))
```

Para A (coluna origem) temos associados os valores: A, B e C. Formando combinações 2 a 2 dos elementos apurados teria A-B, A-C, B-A, B-C, C-A, C-B. O objetivo seria obter a tabela final:

```
   origem x y
1       A B A
2       A B C
3       A A B
4       A A C
5       A C B
6       A C A
7       E C B
8       E B C
9       D A B
10      D B A
```

Neste exemplo tenho 3 valores únicos na “origem”: A, E e D. Cada um desses valores tem pelo menos um correspondente em “destino” (valores únicos com origem em A: A, B, C; valores únicos com origem em E: C e B; valores únicos com origem em D: A e B).

Consigo obter as combinações pretendidas quando filtro por um valor na “origem” no entanto, necessitava generalizar para todos os valores presentes nessa coluna. Alguém consegue ajudar?

Comment: Porque é que para origem D e E só há duas linhas no resultado final? Com origem E também temos 3 letras e 6 pares sem repetições. O mesmo para D.

Comment: Obg pela questão. Editei a pergunta colocando detalhe. O valor E na "origem" tem apenas 2 observações: (E, **C**) e (E, **B**), o que pretendo é combinar os valores “**destino**” 2 a 2 (C, B) i.é: C-B e B-C ( o valor E serve para split da df e apuramento dos destinos a combinar )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução, usando *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, unique(expand.grid(destino, destino)), by = origem][Var1 != Var2]
#>     origem Var1 Var2
#>  1:      A    A    B
#>  2:      A    C    B
#>  3:      A    B    A
#>  4:      A    C    A
#>  5:      A    B    C
#>  6:      A    A    C
#>  7:      E    B    C
#>  8:      E    C    B
#>  9:      D    B    A
#> 10:      D    A    B
```

`expand.grid` gera todas as combinações dos pontos de destino; `data.table` facilita fazer a operação por grupo (ponto de origem, no caso). `unique` remove as combinações duplicadas, geradas porque para uma mesma origem há repetição de destinos. Como não quer as combinações em que as letras são as mesma, essa condição é filtrada do resultado final.